# is there Windows services on winCE?

Tags: windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

is there something like Windows Services for WinCE 6.0 OS?, I mean, a background process thread(s) doing their things...

I need to develop a programm on .NETCF thay always listens to a specific port on device, stores it on SQL Server compact database and sends it back to another port. Don't want to do a desktop app for this as there will be no GUI at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Windows CE supports Services.  *However* a true service must be written in C because the CF doesn't support EE Hosting.  There is a [Codeplex project](http://managedserviceswm.codeplex.com/) to try to make managed services. I've never used it so I can't say I recommend it or not. YMMV.

As far as writing an app with no UI, that doesn't require a service.  Just don't create a Form in your `Main` method.